# What's the form of total wavefunction of Carbon-12: symmetric or asymmetric?

Tags: symmetry, bosons

Considering the two electrons in `2p`, is the total wave function of C-12 (anti)symmetric under particle exchanging in it's ground state? What about other states?

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/330585/36194

Answer (score 1):

The total wavefunction of any system of electrons is **always** antisymmetric with respect to electron exchange.

For the specific case of carbon-12, going by [the NIST Atomic Spectra Database](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html), the ground state has the configuration $2s^22p^2\ {}^3\mathrm P_0$. This makes it a triplet state, so its spin sector is symmetric with respect to exchange, and the $L=1$ spatial part is antisymmetric.

Comment: Isn't a system with even fermions a bosonic system?

Comment: @jdoe That's with respect to interchanging whole copies of the system, i.e. exchanging two whole carbon atoms, not exchanging electrons inside each atom.